# spring boot rest webservice, how to improve a clean code?

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i started a project on spring boot using a rest a webservice, when i shared  it between my team they puted some comments :

- **get** method need to be grouped **Ex :** `get/users & get/users/{id} will be get/users/{id}`
- remove **put** method & just use **post** **Ex:** `post/users/0 add | post/users/{id} update`
- make a **helper class for Jdbc Template** and call it in the repository classes to centralize the code

pls guys help me to solve this i'm so confused, and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> get method need to be grouped Ex : get/users & get/users/{id} will be
>   get/users/{id}

I do not agree with this. `/get/users` will be returning `List<User>` and `get/users/{id}` will return `User` that matches with {id}

---

> remove put method & just use post Ex: post/users/0 add |
>   post/users/{id} update

Post should be used when you create a new resource. POST is not idempotent. Each time you call a post a new resource will be created. 
e.g. Calling POST /Users will create a new User every-time.

PUT on other hands works like upsert. Create if the resource is not present and update/replace if present. Put is idempotent and doesn't change the resource's state even if it's called multiple times.

---

> make a helper class for Jdbc Template and call it in the repository
>   classes to centralize the code

Helper classes help to separate the concerns and achieve single responsibility.

However, JdbcTemplate is a ready to use abstraction of JDBC. I don't see any point in creating Helper. You can create a DataAccessObject (DAO) or Repository which `has-a` JdbcTemplate. Like the two Dao shown below

```
public class UserDao {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public User findUserById(String id){}

    public void addUser(User user){} 
}

//    -------
public class BooksDao{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Book> getAllBooksByType(String type){}

    public void Book getBookByName(String name){} 
}
```

Now, your Dao objects can be called from Controller or if you need to modify data before/after DB operation, best is to have a Service layer between Controller and Dao.

Don't bother too much about recommendations or rules. Stick to the basic OOPS concepts. Those are really easy to understand and implement.

Always:

1. Encapsulate data variables and methods working on those variables together
2. Make sure your class has a Single Responsibility
3. Write smaller and testable methods (if you can't write tests to cover your method, then something is wrong with your method)
4. Always keep the concerns separate
5. Make sure your objects are loosely coupled. (You are already using spring so just use the spring's auto-wiring)

Comment: Thanks for helping !! one more question ^^ !! about the JdbcTemplate is it considered like a helper class or something like that  ?

Comment: @Djamelkr as I mentioned for last point I need to know more about your object structure and if you are using any ORM framework

Comment: no i'm just using the jdbcTemplate of spring , no ORM  , just doing simple call with jdbctemplate !!

Comment: @Djamelkr I have added details around the last point. Check and let me know if you still have questions

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar That was very clear thank you so much ^^ !!